# How to upgrade one individual file from node_modules folder instead of upgrading the whole package

Tags: npm, configuration, node-modules, yarnpkg, raven

I need to upgrade one of the `yarn.lock` file from `node_modules` folder to remove the Raven vulnerabilities issue.

The file path is

> src/node_modules/form-data/yarn.lock

I know I can use `npm install` to install a new package. But is there a way that I can keep the whole package to the current version, but upgrade one file in the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the file directly. Or you can fork the package and update just the file, then publish your fork. But no, there is no way to use `npm` (and presumably not `yarn` either) to update a file without updating the package. That is by design. There are big debugging and malware possibilities if you run an `npm` command and have it report back that you are running version 1.2.3 but in reality you are running version 1.2.3 with one or more files modified.

I'm puzzled a bit by your desire to update a `yarn.lock` file in a package. `yarn.lock` files don't affect anything if they're inside `node_modules`. This is true both for `npm` and `yarn`. The `yarn.lock` file is ignored if it is not in your top-level project. Updating `yarn.lock` inside `node_modules` won't do anything to your running code. Perhaps the dependency is listed in your top-level `yarn.lock` file for your project?